# Importing external libraries like node.js special syntax

Tags: svelte

I'm trying to use an external library in Svelte whose instructions are for node.js, for example:

```
var lunr = require("lunr")
require("lunr-languages/lunr.stemmer.support")(lunr)
require('lunr-languages/lunr.multi')(lunr)
require("lunr-languages/lunr.de")(lunr)
```

The first import I simply converted to `import lunr from "lunr"` and it works as expected (after npm install of course). However, I have no idea how to import the other 3 lines with that special syntax. Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That special syntax is calling the required function with `lunr` as an argument. It can be rewritten as follows:

```js
import lunr from 'lunr';
import stemmerSupport from 'lunr-languages/lunr.stemmer.support';
import multi from 'lunr-languages/lunr.multi';
import de from 'lunr-languages/lunr.de';

stemmerSupport(lunr);
multi(lunr);
de(lunr);
```

Answer (score 1):

When save a plugin with `npm install` command it means it is saved for global use,
from the other hand, when save with `npm --save` command, your package will just appear in your dependencies.

I prefer the first way of installing and declaring plugin globally. Then you can use one of the following initializations inside your main.js

Keep in mind that your default plugin directory is located at project's root folder level, unless you've changed.

```
let pluginName = require('pluginName');
import pluginName from 'pluginDirectoryHere';
import pluginName from '@rootDirectory/pluginDirectory/';
import { pluginName } from 'pluginName'
```

Give it a try
I hope to pin point an approach to your problem :)